# How to produce the theorem environment name inside a theorem-type environment?

Tags: environments, theorems, variable

**Motivation**: I want to declare a command `\tbc` (without arguments) to use it inside an environment. I want this command to produce a text like *Problem 2 continues on the next page*, start a new page and produce *Problem 2 continued...* I use a variety of environments, such as Problem, Question, Exercise, etc, but all use a continuous numbering with the counter `theorem`. Naturally, I want my `\tbc` to produce  *Problem 2* when it's used between `\begin{problem}` and `\end{problem}`, and *Question 3* when it's used between `\begin{question}` and `\end{question}`.

**Question**: I know that I can get the environment number with `\the\value{theorem}`. I can't figure out how to get an environment name.

I am aware that there are other packages for this, but having my own small command allows me to better merge it with the style of my documents.

Answer (score 2):

A hack that exploits `amsthm`: when typesetting the header, I redefine `\tbcname` to expand to `#1` (the theorem name).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{definition-keep}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\gdef\tbcname{#1}\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition-keep}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

\newcommand{\tbc}{%
  \par
  \textit{\tbcname~\thetheorem\ continues on the next page}\clearpage
  \textit{\tbcname~\thetheorem\ continued}\dots\par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
\lipsum[1-3]
\tbc
\lipsum[4]
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case the names of your environments are the same as the names of the counters in use for these environments, you can use `\@currenvir` for obtaining the name of an environment and the counter associated to that environment.

Besides this:

1. The [varioref](https://ctan.org/pkg/varioref)-package can be used for obtaining phrases like "on the next page" or "on the following page". That brings a bit of variety to the text.
2. I think, for referencing from outside the environment the `\autoref`-command of the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-package will be your friend.

   It will prepend names associated to counters to references.

   The names come from macros whose names are of pattern
   `\⟨counter⟩autorefname`
   or—in case the further macro is not defined—
   `\⟨counter⟩name`.
   [(See section 4, Additional User Macros, of the manual of the hyperref-package.)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf#table.12)

   But there is one small problem:

   When you use the same counter for several theorem-like environments, you need several names / several macros  `\⟨counter⟩autorefname` for that counter.

   That problem is addressed by the package [aliascnt](https://ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt) by Heiko Oberdiek.

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}

%===================[adjust margins/layout for the example]====================
\paperwidth=8.91cm
\paperheight=5.25 cm
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\oddsidemargin=1.25cm
\marginparsep=.125\oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth=\oddsidemargin
\advance\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep
\advance\textwidth-2\oddsidemargin
\advance\oddsidemargin-1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\textheight=\paperheight
\topmargin=1.25cm
\footskip=.5\topmargin
{\normalfont\global\advance\footskip.5\ht\strutbox}%
\advance\textheight-2\topmargin
\advance\topmargin-1in
\headheight=0ex
\headsep=0ex
\pagestyle{plain}
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=0ex 
\topsep=0ex
\partopsep=0ex
%==================[eof margin-adjustments]====================================

\usepackage{varioref}

% In case you wish no hyperlinks and no bookmarks:
\AtBeginDocument{\NoHyper}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
% In case you wish hyperlinks and bookmarks:
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{aliascnt}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% Create fake-counters that use the same count-register as the
% theorem-counter:
\newaliascnt{problem}{theorem}
\newaliascnt{question}{theorem}
\newaliascnt{exercise}{theorem}

% Define the autoref-names of the fake-counters when referencing then
% via \autoref
\newcommand\problemautorefname{Problem}
\newcommand\questionautorefname{Question}
\newcommand\exerciseautorefname{Exercise}


% Create theorem-environments that use the fake-counters:
\newtheorem{problem}[problem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{question}[question]{Question}
\newtheorem{exercise}[exercise]{Exercise}

% Apply the fix provided by the package aliascnt for \newtheorem when
% being used with a fake-counter -- see section 1, "User Interface" of
% the manual of the aliascnt-package, URL:
% <http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/aliascnt.pdf>
\aliascntresetthe{problem}
\aliascntresetthe{question}
\aliascntresetthe{exercise}

\makeatletter
%
% \tbc or \tbc[<referencing-command>]
%
\newcommand\tbccnt{0}%
\newcommand{\tbc}[1][\vpageref*]{%
  \par
  % globally step \tbccnt:
  \xdef\tbccnt{\number\numexpr\tbccnt+1\relax}%
  \begingroup
  % You probably wish to adjust varioref's behaviour:
  % \def\reftextfaceafter{on the next page}%
  % \def\reftextafter{on the next page}%
  \textit{%
    \csname\@currenvir autorefname\endcsname~%
    \csname the\@currenvir\endcsname\ continues \null%
    \hyperref[{tbc@continued@\tbccnt}]{#1{tbc@continued@\tbccnt}}.%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \clearpage
  \textit{%
    \phantomsection
    \label{tbc@continued@\tbccnt}%
    \csname\@currenvir autorefname\endcsname~%
    \csname the\@currenvir\endcsname\ continued%
  }\dots\par\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{Firsttheorem}
This is a theorem.
\tbc
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\vfill

\begin{problem}
\label{Firstproblem}
This is a problem.
\tbc
This is a problem.
\end{problem}

\vfill

\begin{question}
\label{Firstquestion}
This is a question.
\tbc
This is a question.
\end{question}

\vfill

\begin{exercise}
\label{Firstexercise}
This is an exercise.
\tbc[on page~\pageref*]
This is an exercise.
\end{exercise}

\newpage

\noindent Referencing:

\verb|\autoref{Firsttheorem}|: \autoref{Firsttheorem}

\verb|\autoref{Firstproblem}|: \autoref{Firstproblem}

\verb|\autoref{Firstquestion|: \autoref{Firstquestion}

\verb|\autoref{Firstexercise}|: \autoref{Firstexercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]